# How can I import a stylesheet from a Node module that is Yarn 2+ Plug-n-Play installed?

Tags: sass, yarnpkg-v3

Got a new job back in January. Our dependencies have *not* been well maintained, and given that the other developer's on vacation for a couple weeks, I've been given carte blanche to get our dependencies as up-to-date as I can in those two weeks.

I hit a bunch of our tooling dependencies this morning, and that went great. Now I'm trying to upgrade to the new Yarn with plug-n-play. (Do I *really* need to? No. But I want to.) I've already cleared up a bunch of not-properly-installed peer dependencies, but now I'm running into stylesheet issues while doing test builds.

The players: Yarn 3.6.0, Sass 1.63.3, Node 20.3.1, using what seems to be the default `react-scripts build` script from react-scripts 5.0.0.

The relevant stylesheet snippet (src/styles/grid.scss):

```scss
@import 'src/styles/variables';
@import 'src/styles/mixins';
@import '~@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css';
@import '~@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css';
@import '~@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css';
@import '~@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css';
@import '~@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids/styles/material.css';
```

The build output:

```
Failed to compile.

Error: Can't resolve '~@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css' in 'src/styles'
```

## Things I tried

I tried `yarn unplug`ging the relevant dependencies (`@syncfusion/ej2-base`, `@syncfusion/ej2-buttons`, `@syncfusion/ej2-navigations`, `@syncfusion/ej2-popups`, `@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids`) but that doesn't seem to give me a stable location that I can reference.

Stripping the .css extension from those imports nets me a new and interesting error, so I don't think changing that is necessarily the way to go.

```
Failed to compile.

SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import 'ej2-icons/styles/material.scss';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  .yarn/cache/@syncfusion-ej2-base-npm-19.1.64-ceb12a3308-4fddcb9449.zip/node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.scss 1:9  @import
  src/styles/grid.scss 3:9                                                                                                           root stylesheet
```

## Things that will probably work, but I'd rather have a better solution

Setting Yarn to `nodeLinker: node-modules` works, but if there's another solution I'd rather use that.

We already have a postinstall script that copies stuff from a module out into the regular filesystem, and updating that wouldn't be difficult. It's inelegant, though I'd be happier about it than the `nodeLinker` option.